# Spring Batch without Spring Cloud Data Flow

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have a Spring Boot application that uses Spring Batch. I want now to implement an admin panel to see all job statuses. For this, Spring has "spring-batch-admin" But I see that is deprecated long time ago:

> The functionality of Spring Batch Admin has been mostly duplicated
>   and 
>       expanded upon via Spring Cloud Data Flow and we encourage all users to 
>       migrate to that going forward.

But then Spring Cloud Data Flow says:

> Pipelines consist of Spring Boot apps, built using the Spring Cloud 
>      Stream or **Spring Cloud Task microservice** frameworks

So in order to use this functionality do I really need to convert my spring boot app to a microservice? Isn't this an overkill just to see some batch statuses? Also I can not install docker on my production server(for various reasons) Can I still use Spring Cloud Data Flow without docker?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, spring boot batch should be wrapped as spring cloud task, which should not be too complicated.
2. If Docker does not suit your needs - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-local-deploying-spring-cloud-dataflow